# What is the “dt” in the complementary filter equation and how do i find out the “dt”?

Tags: kalman-filter

I am going to implement the Complementary filter into my system but i do not quite understand what is the "dt" means and how should i find out the "dt" in the Complementary filter equation. This is where I found out the complementary filter equation https://www.pieter-jan.com/node/11 and this is the equation angle = 0.98 * (agnle + gyrData * dt) + 0.02 * (accData).

Comment: $dt$ is the "timestep".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dt$ is the sample rate in seconds. See the code below the formula which says:
"define dt 0.01"; "10 ms sample rate!".

Comment: Which means that 10 sample data are being captured in 0.01 second?

Comment: No it means that one sample is taken every $0.01$ seconds - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate